# Counting-sort Big O

Tags: big-o

I am trying to figure out big o notation and come up with the cost and times for the counting sort algorithm, however, my answer seems to be wrong. This is what I get.

```
                                   Cost           Time
Counting-sort(A,B, k)                 C1              1 
Let C[0...K] be a new array           C2              1
for i = 0 to k                        C3              K 
    C[i] = 0                          C4              K-1
for j=1 to A.length or n              C5              n
    C[A[j]] = C[A[j]] + 1             C6              n-1   
for i = 1 to k                        C7              K   
    C[i] = C[i] + C[i-1]              C8              K-1
for j=n or A.length down to 1         C9              n 
    B[C[A[j]] = A[j]                  C10             n-1  
    C[A[j]] = C[A[j]] -1              C11             n-1
```

I get 4k + 4n -5, but I see the correct answer is 2k+2n which is O(k + n), why is this wrong?

Comment: Usually a k in calculating complexity can refer to xk where x is a constant. The author of the answer might have omitted some factors in this way. I wouldn't say you are wrong at all since 4k + 4n -4 is O(k + n).

Comment: I don't know the notation you're using, but shouldn't `C4` be 1, and likewise for all the other simple loop bodies? And should you really be adding C3 and C4 in the final result when C4 is part of C3? And isn't C1 just the method header and not a cost? I'm getting 2K+2n+1 (the +1 being the creation of the new array).